# logrotate works when run manually, doesn't when run with cron

Tags: logs, logrotate

This is on Ubuntu Server 14.04, but I think it's applicable to all OSes. I'm running `logrotate` as a cron job, cron settings are the defaults (`logrotate` exists in `/etc/cron.daily`). I'm running a program that's finicky with its log file--the program doesn't end when the log file is touched, but it stops doing anything.

I set `logrotate` with the below config, the scripts in question do nothing but stop and start the given program. When I run `logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf` it works perfectly--the program is killed, all logs are rotated, and the program restarts. When it runs automatically, however, something isn't working--I get up in the morning and the program is running but not doing anything as if its log file were touched while running. The log is rotated, so `logrotate` did that, but it apparently didn't stop/start the program correctly. The scripts do use full paths at all points, nothing is shortened.

Does `logrotate` run as root with its default settings (`logrotate` in `/etc/cron.daily`)? If not, how can I make it do so? Is that even the problem?

Config file with file-specific info removed (except the file with problems):

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be configured here
/home/username/.local/share/bot/bot.log {
    compress
    daily
    nomail
    rotate 14
    prerotate
        /home/username/botscripts/wbstop.sh
    endscript
    postrotate
        /home/username/botscripts/wbstart.sh
    endscript
}
```

In case it's helpful, these are the two scripts. The program takes a few seconds to cleanly shut down, that's why it sleeps. `wbstop.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -INT -f bot.py
sleep 8
```

`wbstart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
python3 /home/username/bot/bot.py &
```

Comment: When it runs under cron, it has a very minimal environment, and likely, a very short path.  In your /home/username scripts, are you relying on any paths to start/stop the executable?  As a first step, go through everything and specify full paths for every executable (even standard OS commands).

Comment: @EightBitTony Just verified, only full paths are used. I've added that to the question as well as the scripts themselves.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin` (or wherever `pkill` and `python3` live) in `$PATH` when `cron` is running? Does it work from cron if you use full paths to those programs?

Comment: @zackse I made the changes (`/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`, respectively), then ran cron with `sudo run-parts /etc/cron.daily`. The rotate ran correctly, though I don't know if `run-parts` properly simulates `cron`. I'll have to wait overnight to verify that it works properly.